# How can I see the body of the static class Enumerable in the 'System.Linq' namespace?

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET 7.0 and I want to see the body of the static class Enumerable in the *System.Linq* namespace.

I've tried <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>, but it doesn't work. And sometimes it opens a partial class with the same name with some methods.

How can I see the body of this class?

Comment: "And sometimes it opens a partial class with the same name with some methods." Are you saying that's *not* the "body" of the class? What do you want to see then?

Comment: [See also](https://source.dot.net/#q=Enumerable)

Comment: The implementation of the System.Linq namespace is spread over many files, so there's no single body for that class.

Answer (score 2):

Often the IDE will do a good job (through the <kbd>F12</kbd> that you mention) via one of:

- source-link
- IL decompilation back into C#
- showing just the metadata

However, if in doubt: the actual source is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq) - that's "current" (8.0 preview), the 7.0 maintenance branch is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/release/7.0/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq); *most* of the files there are the `partial class Enumerable`

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2022 (default configuration), when you "Go to Definition":

1. Try to display the source code

   - a) Search in local source
   - b) Search by SourceLink
2. Open the metadata

---

`Enumerable` isn't in your source code, then SourceLink take a turn. But the type `Enumerable` is [split in several files](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.8/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq):

- Where.cs
- Select.cs
- Take.cs
- ...

Then SourceLink found several files and can't choose. Finally, the metadata is displayed. It was your see.

---

If you "Go to Definition" on a specific `Enumerable` method, then SourceLink found only one file and Visual Studio display it.

Answer (score 0):

To view the implementation of the static class Enumerable in the System.Linq namespace using Visual Studio with .NET 7.0, you can follow these steps:

1-Open the Solution Explorer and navigate to your project.

2-Right-click on the project and select "Add" > "Existing Item".

3-In the "Add Existing Item" dialog, browse to the location of the System.Core.dll assembly file which contains the `System.Linq` namespace. The location of this file depends on your .NET installation, but it is typically found in the .NET installation directory under ReferenceAssemblies.

4-Select the System.Core.dll file and click the "Add" button.

5-In the Solution Explorer, expand the References node and find the `System.Core` reference.

6-Right-click on the `System.Core` reference and select "View in Object Browser".

7-In the Object Browser, navigate to the `System.Linq` namespace and select the Enumerable class.

8-The implementation of the Enumerable class will be displayed in the bottom pane of the Object Browser.
Alternatively, you can use a decompiler tool such as JetBrains dotPeek or Telerik JustDecompile to view the implementation of the Enumerable class. These tools can decompile the .NET assembly and show you the source code of the class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: [`Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-1.0) is in `System.Linq.dll` in .NET Core starting with .NET Core 1.0 and continuing through .NET 8, and in `netstandard.dll` for .NET Standard 2.1.  It's only in `System.Core.dll` in the old .NET Framework and a few others like certain Xamarin versions.